# What's the difference between Rails active record's select and group?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I've been reading through tutorials on Rails' active record model operations. And I'm a little confused on the difference between .select and .group. If I wanted to get all the names of all my users in table User I believe I could do:

```
myUsers = User.select(:name)
```

so how would that be different from saying:

```
myUsers = User.group(:name)
```

thanks,

Will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two differ like this:

```
User.select(:name)
```

is equivalent to this SQL statement

```
SELECT name from users;
```

and

```
User.group(:name)
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT * from users GROUP BY name;
```

The difference is that with `select(:name)` you are taking all rows ordered by `id`, but only with column `name`. With `group(:name)` you are taking all rows **and** all columns, but ordered by column `name`.

`User.pluck(:name)` will be the fastest way to pull all the names from your db.

Answer (score 1):

There is [`#to_sql`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition/to_sql) method to check what *DB* query it is building. By looking at the DB query, you can confirm yourself what is going on. Look the below example :-

```
arup@linux-wzza:~/Rails/tv_sms_voting> rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.4)
>> Vote.group(:choice).to_sql
=> "SELECT \"votes\".* FROM \"votes\"  GROUP BY choice"
>> Vote.select(:choice).to_sql
=> "SELECT \"votes\".\"choice\" FROM \"votes\""
>>
```

Now it is clear that `Vote.select(:choice)` is actually, `SELECT "votes"."choice" FROM "votes"`, which means, select `choice` column from all rows of the table `votes`.

`Vote.group(:choice)` is grouping the rows of the `votes` table, based on the column `choice` and selecting all columns.

> If I wanted to get all the names of all my users in table User.

Better is `User.pluck(:name)`.

Comment: Ok. So would that be any different than something like Vote.all.order(:choice)?

Comment: Doing that will give you all the records (all columns) ordered by `choice` column as opposed to only the `name` column ordered by table id.